# replace a word in text file java

Tags: java, arrays, file-handling

i have my code here:

```
public void Edit()throws IOException{
        FileWriter writeFile=new FileWriter("voters.txt", true);
        BufferedWriter outFile=new BufferedWriter(writeFile);
        File readFile=new File("voters.txt");
        BufferedReader read=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readFile));

        vNumForEdit=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter voters number: ");
        String line=null;
        while((line=read.readLine())!=null){
            String [] info=line.split("/");
            if(info[0].matches(vNumForEdit)){
                String [] forEditMenu={"Name", "Age", "Gender", "Date of Birth", "Place of Birth", "Address", "Civil Status", "Citizenship", "Profession/Occupation", "Father's Name", "Mother's Name"};
                forEdit=(String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, line+"\n\nPlease select what you want to edit", "National Election 2765", 1, null, forEditMenu, forEditMenu[0]);
                switch(forEdit){
                case "Name":
                    newName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new name: ");
                    if(info[1].matches(oldName)){
                        outFile.append(info[1]=newName);
                        outFile.close();
                    }
                    read.close();

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the text file looks like this

```
1/d/19/Male/e//s/Single/v/e/e/f
2/c/98/Male//d/c/Single/r/w/q/d
```

as you can see i made the info/line as array so it can read the value in index 0 which is the voting number. the task is the user will input the voters number and then if it's found, the user will enter again what does he want to edit. i use array as well to determine the name, age, gender, etc. the array is like this:

```
info[0] = voters number
info[1]= name
info[2] = age
info[3] = date of birth
info[4]= place of birth
info[5] = status
info[6] = citizenship
info[7] = profession
info[8] = father's name
info[9] = mother's name
```

but my code always end up with error `java.lang.NullPointerException`. most of my variables there are declared globally

EDITED: here's the error/stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.matches(Unknown Source)
    at lozada.My_Voting_System_Official.Edit(My_Voting_System_Official.java:135)
    at lozada.My_Voting_System_Official.Menu(My_Voting_System_Official.java:43)
    at lozada.My_Voting_System_Official.main(My_Voting_System_Official.java:15)
```

Comment: Please include the stack trace.

Comment: Which line in the code do you get the NPE ?

Comment: Also, use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `matches` for if check if its regular string.

Comment: @Veluria i already add it :)

Comment: @Sachin i (think)i add the which line got an error hehehe :)

Comment: @bruh that explains it. use `equals` instead of `matches`

Comment: @Sachin it was saved tho. but it was not edited. like if it enters 1, the line that has voters number of 1 (w/c is in the info[0]), the name should be edited (w/c is in the info[1]) with what the user entered in the newName

Comment: @Sachin also there's another error/stack error now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104789/discussion-between-sachin-and-bruh).

Answer (score 0):

i think you didn't declare the oldName Variable 
in this code

```html
if(info[1].matches(oldName)){
                        outFile.append(info[1]=newName);
                        outFile.close();
                    }
```

Comment: vNumForEdit and oldName are not declared .

Comment: most of my variables are declared globally  :)

Comment: well the stack trance says otherwise. " Unknown Source "

Comment: Put a breakpoint at that line, run the code is a debugger, and then see if oldName is declared. Ps use .equals